# Merging and sorting lists: Complexity

Tags: python, sorting, merge, complexity-theory

I am writing a code in order to return a list that is the sorted merge of other two sorted lists. The exercise requires that the complexity has O(n+m) where n and m are the elements in the two lists to merge. I solved the exercise and think the complexity is the correct one, but I'm not definitely sure, may I kindly as you to give it a look?

```
def merge1(a,b):
    last=-1
    saved=[]
    while a!=[] and b!=[]:
        current_max=max(a[last], b[last])
        saved.append(current_max)
        if current_max==a[-1]:
            a.pop()
        else:
            b.pop()
```

Until here the complexity is for sure the correct one, I am unsure about the following

```
    if a==[]:
        for el in range(len(b)):
            saved.append(max(b))
            b.pop()
    else:
        for el in range(len(a)):
            saved.append(max(a))
            a.pop()
    saved.reverse()
    return saved
```

I imagine that the complexity could be reduced using only various `if` and avoiding the last `for` cycle, but could you please give me your opinion about my code anyway? Thx guys.

Comment: are both the lists sorted?

Comment: yes they are both sorted

Comment: first one is O(m+n).

Comment: If you compare from both the end of the two list, and you can use `saved.append(b)` , that's a total O(m+n) complexity becuase you can compare at most m+n-1 times. But now your using `saved.append(max(b))` introduces more complexity.

Comment: Your algorithm is O(m+n). The exact boound is 2*(m+n) because you iterate each element in m+n and then the reverse() at the end is another m+n.

Comment: However the complexity of list.append() and list.pop() is a factor. If this is just "theoretical code" that assumes pop and append are constant, that's ok. In python, append and pop are "amortized constant".